# when resizing screen, left margin stays the same and the right margin shrinks

Tags: html, css

im new to web design, getting a understanding for it now though and enjoying it, ive searched my question for awhile now and getting no where with it, hope someone can help me out!
So my problem is, my left margin is set at 25% and the right margin is set at 25%
my width of the div is set to 750px
so when i go to resize the screen, the right margin shrinks but the left margin stays at 25%!!!!
this means when viewing it on my mobile or a smaller screen, the website looks like its more to the right hand side...
my website is http://lawrencetrigg.tk if anybody could suggest what my issue is, would help me loads!
Thanks guys!

```css
a:-webkit-any-link{
text-decoration:none !important;
}
body {
 background-color: black;
}
#top {
 position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
 background-image: url("images/background-top-one.jpg");
 background-repeat: repeat-x;
   left: 25%;
   right: 25%;
  width: 750px;
   height: 100%;
 text-align:center;
 
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-right: auto;

}
#bottom1 {
 
 position: fixed;

 background-image: url("images/background-bottom-one.jpg");
 
 bottom: 0px;
    left: 25%;
    right: 25%;
    width: 750px;
    height: 150px; 
 color: black;
 text-align:center;
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-right: auto;
}

div.transbox {
font-size: 16px;

  margin: 30px;
  background-color: #AAAAAA;
  border: 1px solid black;
  opacity: 0.7;
  filter: alpha(opacity=60); /* For IE8 and earlier */
}

div.transbox p {
  margin: 5%;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #000000;
}
 div.col-top-one {
 float: left;
 width: 100%;
 font-size: 20px;
 padding: 1px;

 height: 250px;

 
 border-color: white;
 color: white;
 top: 50px;
}

ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #333;
 top: 0px;
}


li {
    float: left;
}

li a {
    display: inline-block;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover {
    background-color: #111;
}


a.tooltip {outline:none; }
a.tooltip strong {line-height:30px;}
a.tooltip:hover {text-decoration:none;} 
a.tooltip span {
    z-index:10;display:none; padding:14px 20px;
    margin-top:60px; margin-left:-160px;
    width:300px; line-height:16px;
}
a.tooltip:hover span{
    display:inline; position:absolute; 
    border:2px solid #FFF;  color:#EEE;
    background:#333 url(cssttp/css-tooltip-gradient-bg.png) repeat-x 0 0;
}
.callout {z-index:20;position:absolute;border:0;top:-14px;left:120px;}
    
/*CSS3 extras*/
a.tooltip span
{
    border-radius:2px;        
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px 4px #666;
    /*opacity: 0.8;*/
}
</style>
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Lawrence Trigg</title>
<link rel="images/favicon.ico" href="images/favicon.ico">
<style type="text/css">
a:-webkit-any-link{
text-decoration:none !important;
}
body {
 background-color: black;
}
#top {
 position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
 background-image: url("images/background-top-one.jpg");
 background-repeat: repeat-x;
   left: 25%;
   right: 25%;
  width: 750px;
   height: 100%;
 text-align:center;
 
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-right: auto;

}
#bottom1 {
 
 position: fixed;

 background-image: url("images/background-bottom-one.jpg");
 
 bottom: 0px;
    left: 25%;
    right: 25%;
    width: 750px;
    height: 150px; 
 color: black;
 text-align:center;
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-right: auto;
}

div.transbox {
font-size: 16px;

  margin: 30px;
  background-color: #AAAAAA;
  border: 1px solid black;
  opacity: 0.7;
  filter: alpha(opacity=60); /* For IE8 and earlier */
}

div.transbox p {
  margin: 5%;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #000000;
}
 div.col-top-one {
 float: left;
 width: 100%;
 font-size: 20px;
 padding: 1px;

 height: 250px;

 
 border-color: white;
 color: white;
 top: 50px;
}

ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #333;
 top: 0px;
}


li {
    float: left;
}

li a {
    display: inline-block;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover {
    background-color: #111;
}


a.tooltip {outline:none; }
a.tooltip strong {line-height:30px;}
a.tooltip:hover {text-decoration:none;} 
a.tooltip span {
    z-index:10;display:none; padding:14px 20px;
    margin-top:60px; margin-left:-160px;
    width:300px; line-height:16px;
}
a.tooltip:hover span{
    display:inline; position:absolute; 
    border:2px solid #FFF;  color:#EEE;
    background:#333 url(cssttp/css-tooltip-gradient-bg.png) repeat-x 0 0;
}
.callout {z-index:20;position:absolute;border:0;top:-14px;left:120px;}
    
/*CSS3 extras*/
a.tooltip span
{
    border-radius:2px;        
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px 4px #666;
    /*opacity: 0.8;*/
}


<div id="top">


<ul>
  <li><a class="active" href="index.html">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="education.html">Education</a></li>
  <li><a href="#skills.html">Skills</a></li>
  <li><a href="#work.html">Work</a></li>
  <li><a href="#gym.html">Gym</a></li>
  <li><a href="images/cv/lawrencecv2016.docx">Download CV</a></li>
  
  <a href="https://www.facebook.com/Lawrencetrigg" class="tooltip">
    <img src="images/icons/social-facebook32.png" onmouseover="this.src='images/icons/social-facebook322.png'" onmouseout="this.src='images/icons/social-facebook32.png'"  />
    <span>
        <img class="callout" src="images/callout_black.gif" />
        <img src="images/icons/social-facebook32.png" style="float:right;" />
        <strong>Facebook</strong><br />

    </span>
</a>
  <a href="https://www.steam.com" class="tooltip">
    <img src="images/icons/social-steam32.png" onmouseover="this.src='images/icons/social-steam322.png'" onmouseout="this.src='images/icons/social-steam32.png'"  />
    <span>
        <img class="callout" src="images/callout_black.gif" />
        <img src="images/icons/social-steam32.png" style="float:right;" />
        <strong>Steam</strong><br />

    </span>
</a>
 <a href="https://www.youtube.com" class="tooltip">
    <img src="images/icons/social-youtube32.png" onmouseover="this.src='images/icons/social-youtube322.png'" onmouseout="this.src='images/icons/social-youtube32.png'"  />
    <span>
        <img class="callout" src="images/callout_black.gif" />
        <img src="images/icons/social-youtube32.png" style="float:right;" />
        <strong>Youtube</strong><br />

    </span>
</a>
 <a href="https://www.dropbox.com" class="tooltip">
    <img src="images/icons/social-dropbox32.png" onmouseover="this.src='images/icons/social-dropbox322.png'" onmouseout="this.src='images/icons/social-dropbox32.png'"  />
    <span>
        <img class="callout" src="images/callout_black.gif" />
        <img src="images/icons/social-dropbox32.png" style="float:right;" />
        <strong>Dropbox</strong><br />

    </span>
</a>
 <a href="https://www.skype.com" class="tooltip">
    <img src="images/icons/social-skype32.png" onmouseover="this.src='images/icons/social-skype322.png'" onmouseout="this.src='images/icons/social-skype32.png'"  />
    <span>
        <img class="callout" src="images/callout_black.gif" />
        <img src="images/icons/social-skype32.png" style="float:right;" />
        <strong>Skype</strong><br />

    </span>
</a>
  <a href="https://www.google.com" class="tooltip">
    <img src="images/icons/social-googleplus32.png" onmouseover="this.src='images/icons/social-googleplus322.png'" onmouseout="this.src='images/icons/social-googleplus32.png'"  />
    <span>
        <img class="callout" src="images/callout_black.gif" />
        <img src="images/icons/social-googleplus32.png" style="float:right;" />
        <strong>Google Plus</strong><br />

    </span>
</a>


</ul>
<div class="col-top-one">



 <div class="transbox">
    <p>Lawrence William Trigg</p>
 <p>I am a bright, young and ambitious individual who is self-motivated and organised. I can work well under pressure and am able to meet targets and deadlines, I am eager to learn new skills and feel the ones currently gained give a vast and varied history to draw from and implement in new situations. Working well within a team is something I enjoy, however I am also capable of working under my own initiative. </p>
 </div>
<div class="transbox">
    <p>Under Construction</p>
 
 </div>
 </div> 

</div>
<div id="bottom1">
<a href="#" class="tooltip">
    <img src="images/icons/icon-mobile1.png" onmouseover="this.src='images/icons/icon-mobile2.png'" onmouseout="this.src='images/icons/icon-mobile1.png'" />
    <span>
        <img class="callout" src="images/callout_black.gif" />
        <img src="images/icons/icon-mobile1.png" style="float:right;" />
        <strong>Mobile Number</strong><br />
        0481718550
    </span>
</a>
<a href="#" class="tooltip">
    <img src="images/icons/icon-email1.png" onmouseover="this.src='images/icons/icon-email2.png'" onmouseout="this.src='images/icons/icon-email1.png'"  />
    <span>
        <img class="callout" src="images/callout_black.gif" />
        <img src="images/icons/icon-email1.png" style="float:right;" />
        <strong>Email Address</strong><br />
        lawrencetrigg@me.com
    </span>
</a>
<a href="#" class="tooltip">
    <img src="images/icons/icon-picture1.png" onmouseover="this.src='images/icons/icon-picture2.png'" onmouseout="this.src='images/icons/icon-picture1.png'"  />
    <span>
        <img class="callout" src="images/callout_black.gif" />
        <img src="images/icons/icon-picture1.png" style="float:right;" />
        <strong>Name</strong><br />
        Lawrence William Trigg
    </span>
</a>
<a href="#" class="tooltip">
    <img src="images/icons/icon-home1.png" onmouseover="this.src='images/icons/icon-home2.png'" onmouseout="this.src='images/icons/icon-home1.png'"  />
    <span>
        <img class="callout" src="images/callout_black.gif" />
        <img src="images/icons/icon-home1.png" style="float:right;" />
        <strong>Test</strong><br />
     Home
    </span>
</a>
<a href="#" class="tooltip">
    <img src="images/icons/icon-favorite1.png" onmouseover="this.src='images/icons/icon-favorite2.png'" onmouseout="this.src='images/icons/icon-favorite1.png'"  />
    <span>
        <img class="callout" src="images/callout_black.gif" />
        <img src="images/icons/icon-favorite1.png" style="float:right;" />
        <strong>Test</strong><br />
     Favorite
    </span>
</a>
<a href="#" class="tooltip">
    <img src="images/icons/icon-website1.png" onmouseover="this.src='images/icons/icon-website2.png'" onmouseout="this.src='images/icons/icon-website1.png'"  />
    <span>
        <img class="callout" src="images/callout_black.gif" />
        <img src="images/icons/icon-website1.png" style="float:right;" />
        <strong>Test</strong><br />
     Website
    </span>
</a>
<a href="#" class="tooltip">
    <img src="images/icons/icon-dob1.png" onmouseover="this.src='images/icons/icon-dob2.png'" onmouseout="this.src='images/icons/icon-dob1.png'"  />
    <span>
        <img class="callout" src="images/callout_black.gif" />
        <img src="images/icons/icon-dob1.png" style="float:right;" />
        <strong>Date Of Birth</strong><br />
   8th May 1989 / 26 Years old
    </span>
</a>
<a href="#" class="tooltip">
    <img src="images/icons/icon-location1.png" onmouseover="this.src='images/icons/icon-location2.png'" 

<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false -->
```

```
    <span>
        <img class="callout" src="images/callout_black.gif" />
        <img src="images/icons/icon-location1.png" style="float:right;" />
        <strong>Test</strong><br />
     Location
    </span>
</a>


</div>
```

Comment: Site layout from scratch is extremely hard thing to implement right even if some expertise available in the fields of HTML and CSS. If you a new to web design it is best to start with complete solutions such as [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) and then alter it by adding custom theme.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `left` and `right` `position` on this element by that :

```
#top {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    background-image: url("images/background-top-one.jpg");
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 750px;
    height: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

And this `position` of this element by that :

```
#bottom1 {
    position: fixed;
    background-image: url("images/background-bottom-one.jpg");
    bottom: 0px;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 750px;
    height: 150px;
    color: black;
    text-align: center;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

And now it should works :)

Comment: Cheers man actually works like a charm! appreciate the reply! :)